ubuntu 24.04 install stuck at step disk setup
I want to install Ubuntu 24.04 desktop, but I always get stuck at the disk setup step. I want to create a dual boot alongside Windows 11 (existing) on the same SSD. The 'Next' button is not clickable and there is no option to choose

Your install media may be bad. This is the link to the info you need to make sure you have a good download. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

I checked the iso is the same as with SHA256 on the official Ubuntu website @David screenshot

I have had the exact same problem since 24.04 was released three months ago.  I tried again today, with the installer updated to the latest version: always that problem.  Is Canonical aware of that?

Also tried with the recently released 24.04.1 : the problem is still present (at least with my laptop).
